# Eclipse EMF UI ViewerPane

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I have a eclipse emf editor which extends MultiPageEditorPart. This editor class is generated via Eclipse EMF.

In this generated class there is initialization of ViewerPane. We want to show XML errors in this ViewerPane Page. Not in a second page like a ProblemEditorPart, where it is possible to setDiagnostic and setMarkerHelper...

In this link you can find the code, which is similar to what I have.

https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-java/blob/master/de.vogella.emf.webpage.model.editor/src/de/vogella/emf/webpage/model/webpage/presentation/WebpageEditor.java

Is it possible to show error markers in ViewerPane Page of Eclipse emf ?